# File upload callback in Agile tookit

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

I have a agile File input, im using the model File from addons, at the moment without any extend or modifications.

```
    $f=$this->add('Form');
    $modelo  = $this->add($this->model);

    $f->addField('upload','Upload_test','Upload Test')->setModel($modelo);
    $elemento = $this->add('HtmlElement');

    $t = $this;

    $modelo->addHook('afterSave',function($m) use($t, $elemento)
    {

        $t->js(true)->univ()->alert('Uploaded!');
        $elemento->set('Uploaded');

    });

    $f->onSubmit(function($f) use($t){
        $t->js(true)->univ()->alert(333)->execute();
    });
```

The callback are triggering but, any modifications to the actual html are failed, also any js like the simple alert saying Uploaded. How can I execute some PHP like $elemento->set('Uploaded'); to inform of the recently uploaded file? The JS with the alert also doesnt work :(

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: what you are trying to do ??? you just want to upload the file right?? if so then let me know..

Comment: The file contains, values in CSV, once the file is uploaded I want to parse it checking all the values, and show in the page any kind of notification in case of success or error.. Im not able to do show or add any to the page or html..
thanks!

Comment: hey i am not sure about how to read and show the value but yeah if you are facing any problem in uploading and successful msg then you can try the sample, actually I created it for my blog to show how to upload the file in php, so if it will help you out check it.. 
[download](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2VEpvMWpYQ2tKblU)

Comment: thanks for the example, but I prefer keep using the agile File form mechanisms.. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: One idea - maybe in onSubmit callback you need to add $f->update();

Comment: And one more - try moving your alerts in onSubmit method. Do they work there? If so, then tr moving all afterSave callback in onSubmit callback method and also use not $modelo, but $f->model instead. Most likely in onSubmit there is another model object (clone) used and not original one. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The upload element will have an event "upload" triggered as soon as upload is finished.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/templates/js/ui.atk4_uploader.js#L196

You can fetch data from element's data().

Comment: btw - i've just committed another call-back: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commit/b36cc34d470f7739e61ccd19893955b5e1848e40